# Kdenlive preserves original quality

Tags: video-quality, audio-quality, kdenlive

Sometimes I use Kdenlive to cut videos because it is convenient. Something bothering me is that the application goes to the re-render process which has no point. I also have no idea what quality to select. Anything random I choose will either loose quality or takes space of my disk inefficiently. I only have one clip in the entire track. What I would like to do is that I want to cut the video without re-rendering.

Unfortunately, some [responses](https://forum.kde.org/viewtopic.php?f=265&t=114215) from Kdenlive experts is heart-breakening, empty of sympathy to none-experts and not understanding the selling points of their lovely software for the people.

I do not want to use command-line tools nor find the way to tell me the quality of the original video. I expect the tools does this for me. Can I do this with the current release version of Kdenlive?

Comment: I don't think kdenlive can do losless cutting.

Answer (score 0):

If you only have 1 clip, you should be able to do lossless cutting using extract Zone in the clip monitor. The dialog for extract zone offers a codec 'copy' option as well as an encoding option. I have seen it mentioned elsewhere that the timing on the extract Zone function in kdenlive can be a little off at times so you might not be able to do precise cuts reliably, but it should work fine for rough cuts. Note that extract zone is not an option in the project monitor.